# What is the sort-of grass like plant in my border

Tags: identification

Garden Context:
Sunny South-facing Garden in North London, UK. Appers not hugely cared-for in the last decade.

Border Context:
This photo is taken facing about North-North-East:
[image]

My experience:
Almost None! This is my First garden and I'm just learning the ropes.

---

I've started weeding through the over grown borders of the garden and left behind some plants I didn't recognise.

This plant looks sort of like a moss or grass? I believe the thing beside it is a Wood Aven

What is it?

(No idea what sort of search terms to try. "UK grass-like plant" seems not worth trying :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be Irish Moss (Sagina subulata). It's a neat (in terms of growth habit) groundcover that will have tiny white flowers on it in a couple of weeks (looks like it's in bud already). In two of the nurseries I worked at it was a "pot weed"; this is how it entered my garden. Personally, I rather like it as it's easy to move/kill if it starts growing where I don't want it. It also seems to do a pretty good job of not allowing weed seeds to germinate.

EDIT - I should add that I'm familiar with this plant from a colder, drier climate than your own; it may be a more rampant spreader in London than in my state in the US.